# $f(x) = ax \text{ mod } m$, given that $\text{gcd}(a,m) = d$ what values does $f(x)$ take on?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

What values are in the range of $f(x) = ax \: (\text{mod } m)$ for $x \in \{0,...,m-1\}$.

I know that the answer should be all multiples of d however I'm not sure how one would reach that conclusion

Comment: **Hint** $\ \exists\, x\!:\  f \equiv ax\pmod{\!m}\iff \exists\,x,y\!:\ f = ax+my\iff \gcd(a,m)\mid f\ $ by Bezout. $\ \ $

Comment: This shows that $d|f$, but it doesn't necessarily imply that the outputs will me multiples of $d$

Comment: you can use `\bmod` instead of `\text{ mod }`